# Disable right click in GTK window

Tags: python, webkit, contextmenu, pygtk, right-click

I would disable right click (and so context menu) in a Python GTK window (pyGTK) where inside is located a "window" pyWebKitGtk.

Someone can help me writing some lines of code?
I think that would better delete event directly in pyGTK but if you know how don't show context menu in pyWebKitGtk is good anyway.

TNK TNK TNK

Realy cutted code:

```
import gtk
import webkit

window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

browser = webkit.WebView()
browser.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
scroller = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
scroller.add(browser)
window.add(scroller)

window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [enable-default-context-menu](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk-WebKitWebSettings.html#WebKitWebSettings--enable-default-context-menu) setting:

```
webview.props.settings.props.enable_default_context_menu = False
```

Comment: (Sorry for not responding earlier.) If I add the line I posted to your code (above `browser.open`, and with `browser` instead of `webview`) the context menu doesn't appear anymore... So could you clarify in what way my solution doesn't work?