# Webkit context-menu

Tags: python, webkit, contextmenu

I have a little program with a webkit window inside (realy cutted code attached), I would disable the context-menu, but I don't know how..

I found this '**enable-default-context-menu**': http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk-WebKitWebSettings.html, but I can't make it work..
Can you help me?

TNK

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk
import webkit
from webkit import WebView

window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

browser = webkit.WebView()
browser.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
scroller = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
scroller.add(browser)
window.add(scroller)

settings = browser.get_settings()
settings.set_property('enable-default-context-menu', False)

window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: For me the `settings.set_property('enable_default_context_menu', False)` was worked

Answer (score 3):

Going by the seat of my pants here, but try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gtk
import webkit

browser = webkit.WebView()
settings = browser.get_settings()
settings.set_property('enable-default-context-menu', False)
browser.set_settings(settings)    # Push the changed settings back!

scroller = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
scroller.add(browser)

window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
window.add(scroller)

browser.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.. seems that set_property doesn't "know" enable-default-context-menu..   Have someone another idea?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works fine for me... using pywebkit 1.1.7  (Linux Ubuntu)
What version of pywebkit do you have?

p.s. you should have edited your previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445065/disable-right-click-in-gtk-window) instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks Dave. It's interesting... I use, too, pywebkit 1.1.7 on Windows.. However if you say that work for you I'll try on another configuration, os. TNK